# Stick a cell to the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, user-experience

I try to develop an apps using Objective-C on X-Code 7.

Supposed that I have added a **Table View** and some **Table View Cell** on the **UITableViewController**. I have added all of the **Table View Cell** and I need to separate the 'The Footer' to stick on the bottom.

How to separate 'The Footer' so it can stick to the bottom of the screen?

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you are asking?

Comment: footer of tableview does not solve ur problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have 2 solutions (at least).

## Solution 1

(**Warning**! Don't do this! Implementation of this version is faster, but this is very very bad practice)
Anyways...
  In your TableViewController's .m file:

```
@interface TableViewController()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *myTableView;
@end

@implementation TableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat footerHeight = 60;
    self.myTableView = self.tableView;

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    self.view.backgroundColor = self.myTableView.backgroundColor;
    CGRect frame = self.myTableView.frame;
    frame.size.height -= footerHeight;
    self.myTableView.frame = frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myTableView];   

    //Create your footer view, set frame to it and add as subView
    UIView *footerView = ...
    footerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.myTableView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, footerHeight);
    [self.view addSubview:footerView];
}
//...
@end
```

Note that this is a fast written code directly in SO editor, so some syntax errors possible.

## Solution 2

(Recommended solution)

Create a new ViewController in your storyboard and a create new class derived from UIViewController (say ParentVC) and set that class name to that ViewController in the storyboard. Add a Container, and a UIView (place that at the bottom. This will be your footer view). Embed your TableViewController in the Container. 
It will looks like this:
[image]

From TableViewController you can access to ParentVC by calling
`(ParentVC *)self.parentViewController`.
And vice versa: from parent you can call:
`(TableViewController *)self.childViewControllers.firstObject`.